# Send Guzzle's "async" request without calling "wait"

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm trying to send a request to an endpoint, but I don't want to wait for them to respond, as I don't need the response. So I'm using Guzzle, here's how:

```php
$url = 'http://example.com';

$client = new \Guzzelhttp\Client();
$promise = $client->postAsync($url, [
    'headers' => ['Some headers and authorization'],
    'query' => [
        'params' => 'params',
    ]
])->then(function ($result) {
    // I don't need the result. So I just leave it here.
});

$promise->wait();
```

A I understood, I have to call the `wait` method on the `client` in order to actually send the request. But it's totally negates the request being "async" because if the url was not accessible or the server was down, the application would wait for a timeout or any other errors.

So, the question here is, what does Guzzle mean by "async" when you have to wait for the response anyway? And how can I call a truly async request with PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is:

```
    $url = 'http://example.com';

    $client = new \Guzzelhttp\Client();
    $promise = $client->postAsync($url, [
        'headers' => ['Some headers and authorization'],
        'query' => [
            'params' => 'params',
        ]
    ])->then(function ($result) {
         return $result->getStatusCode();
    })
->wait();

echo $promise;
```

You need the `wait()` to be called as the last line so you get the result which will come from your promise.

In this case it will return just the status code.

Just as mentioned in Github is not able to "fire and forget"so i think what you are trying to achieve, like a complete promise like in Vue or React won't work for you here the way you want it to work.

Another approach and what i do personally is to use a `try-catch` on guzzle requests, so if there is a guzzle error then you catch it and throw an exception.

Comment: As I mentioned, it doesn't send the request unless you call `wait` method. I tried it without `wait`, the promise's status would remain at `pending`.

Comment: I think this will answer your question then. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429. I will edit my answer in a min as well

Answer (score 2):

Call `then()` method if you don't want to wait for the result:

```
$client = new GuzzleClient();
$promise = $client->getAsync($url)
$promise->then();
```

Empty `then()` call will make an HTTP request without waiting for result, Very similar to

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false)
```

Comment: Actually, after running some tests, I conclude this isn't the case. What `then()` does is it allows you to continue executing your script without waiting for the request, but the request still isn't actually sent until you eventually call `wait()` (which might happen implicitly when your script terminates).

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;


...Some Code here

$prom = Http::timeout(1)->async()->post($URL_STRING, $ARRAY_DATA)->wait();

... Some more important code here

return "Request sent"; //OR whatever you need to return
```

This works for me as I don't need to know the response always.
It still uses `wait()` but because of the small timeout value it doesn't truly wait for the response.

Hope this helps others.